# Intellij IDEA Generating Persistence Mappings by database schema

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I am brand new to Hibernate and I am trying to generate enitty classes, by database schema in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.1. I create a new project with Java EE Persistence persistence.xml version 2.0, Hibernate provider and use library JPA 2.1-2.1. I have included in project library "hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar".
But in Persistence tool window there is no child nodes: persistence.xml and NewPersistenceUnit. When i right-click on parent node "Generate Persistence Mappings" -> "By Databse Schema" nothing happens.
My persistence.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Does anybody know why "By Database Schema" doesn't work?

Comment: is JPA or Hibernate facet enabled for your module (Project structure)? and do you have an associated database connection and synchronized schema (Database view)?

Comment: In Project Structure -> Facets -> JPA there is a "JPA Configurator Descriptor" string with path .....\src\META-INF\persistence.xm. I have syncronized schema (data source) in Database plugin, and i can view tables through it. But in file persistence.xml in string <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> name of class HibernatePersistence is 
strikethrough, tooltip indicates that it deprecated. Any ideas?

Comment: the newer provider is org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.
is [Hibernate plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-hibernate-support.html) enabled? are there any errors/problems in Project Structure view?

Comment: Yuri, thank you! Problem solved by installing the Hibernate plugin.